# Disable text input from UITextField that has an inputView

Tags: objective-c

I have an `UITextField` that on click shows a `pickerView`. What I want is to disable any input (keyboard or paste) from the `UITextField` and accept only the values selected from the `pickerView`.

I already created the `pickerView` and I've set it as `inputView` of the `UITextField` the problem is that I can still input custom text inside it.
I've tried with:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    return NO;
}
```

But it didn't work.. can someone explain me how to do it?

Comment: what about setEditable:NO ?

Comment: @user3351949 no because then clicking it won't trigger the inputView

Comment: Did you set your text field delegate? I have also used this way, it work perfectly.

Comment: @Signo Adding UITapGestureRecognizer snd setting editable to NO won't trigger the input view?